# gcs-fetcher does not unzip my App Engine source code properly. Missing files

Tags: google-cloud-build

After uploading a zip of my Nodejs source code to GCS, and then calling the `POST https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=apps/*/services/*}/versions` REST API, the Cloud-Builders fetch that zip and deploy my app properly, except it is missing files nested under subfolders. This used to work until October 19. I can see that since October, the Cloud Build's log sends the following warning:

```
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcs-fetcher
WARNING: -type=Archive is deprecated; use -type=ZipArchive
```

What's the difference between an `-type=Archive` and a `-type=ZipArchive`?

I feel that's the problem that causes my zip to be badly unzipped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing that you've opened an issue with the gcs-fetcher team on github as well.

For the time being have you had a look at [gsutil](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/gsutil) it should allow you to do the same process if I haven't misunderstood your needs.

This might be relevant to you.

Let me know.

Comment: I've built my own deployment tool on top of the Google APIs to overcome some limitations of gsutil. I'managed to deploy by uploading each file one by one and then using a manifest instead of using a zip (which is how gsutil does it too).  The zip deployment was working a few days ago. I've looked into the gcs-fetcher source code, and I can see tha there is this weird new difference between an `Archive` and a `ZipArchive`, but I could not figure out what that difference was.

Comment: I'm glad that you managed to find a workaround, I've been looking into finding the difference between Archive and ZipArchive that you mention and I haven't seen any relevant information, surely in the github issue that you've raised they will be able to help us, as I would also like to know the answer to your question.